# Loading a page that doesn't exist yet with application cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, application-cache

I am trying to make my Rails application work offline using application cache and IndexedDB.

The app allows the user to create a new audit, by clicking a "New Audit" link which creates a new audit in the database and then redirects the user to a page for that audit, for example:

```
example.com/audits/63
```

I want the user to be able to create a new audit even while they are offline, which will be stored on local storage and synced to the db when they are back online. However, when I click "New Audit" while my app is offline, I cannot access the page because it hasn't been cached yet. How can I generate a page that doesn't exist yet while I am offline? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pre-populate HTML5 offline appcache for a UIWebView in an iOS application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126462/pre-populate-html5-offline-appcache-for-a-uiwebview-in-an-ios-application)